# wxGrid bind a single cell to event

Tags: events, binding, grid, wxpython

I am trying to do the following:

```
cell = self.grid.SetCellValue(0, 0, "test")  # Where grid is the instance of wx.grid
                                             # and self is a wx.panel instance
self.grid.Bind(EVT_GRID_CELL_LEFT_CLICK, self.on_left_click, cell)
```

this is my attempt at binding the event of clicking cell (0, 0) to self.on_left_click().

But this method binds all cells to this event in the event of a left click.
Is there a way to bind ONLY cell (0, 0) and no other cells?

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution might be to check the event's row and column in your event handler, and perform your actions only if the event came from cell (0,0):

```
def on_left_click(self, evt):
    if evt.GetRow() == 0 and evt.GetCol() == 0:
        #do stuff
    evt.Skip()
```